# Split PHP array into two equal sets where the sum of value are equal

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, sum

I have the below array of players and their points. I want to split them into two equal teams where the sum of the points should be equal where possible.

E.g output should be:

team a = player id's 505, 481, 510, points total is 6

team b = player id's 504, 509, 513, points total is 6

Please can you help point me in the right direction on how to achieve this?

Thank you

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [match_id] => 664
            [0] => 664
            [player_id] => 505
            [1] => 505
            [Points] => 4
            [2] => 4
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [match_id] => 664
            [0] => 664
            [player_id] => 481
            [1] => 481
            [Points] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [match_id] => 664
            [0] => 664
            [player_id] => 510
            [1] => 510
            [Points] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [match_id] => 664
            [0] => 664
            [player_id] => 504
            [1] => 504
            [Points] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [match_id] => 664
            [0] => 664
            [player_id] => 509
            [1] => 509
            [Points] => 4
            [2] => 4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [match_id] => 664
            [0] => 664
            [player_id] => 513
            [1] => 513
            [Points] => 1
            [2] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Start by using `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()` and then you will at least get the data only once as an assoc array and not an assoc and a numeric array

Comment: Number of players need to be equal also? You can try to sort array by points, and add one by one player from the one with highest points to lowest.

usort can help you with that. [usort - manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

`function sortByPoints($a,$b){
  return strcmp($a->Points,$b->Points);
}

usort($array,'sortByPoints');`

Comment: How are you retrieving the data? If you are querying from a set or database, then I think your first step should be to improve the query to get a more workable result. Most interfaces would let you query by player and sum the points. Meaning you can easily build an assoc. array with only player ID and total. Then a simple sort will put all those with similar scores closest.

Comment: Thanks all for you help and advice. I modified the query to sort by points. then done a fetch assoc and split the array in two, odd and even.

Answer (score 1):

So this problem is a partitioning optimization problem, which, guess what, is NP-complete! So you should really specify if you need the *best* result or an *acceptable* result, because it makes a huge difference in terms of algorithm and computing time. If you have a very small data set, the best result can be calculated quickly enough, but if your teams are large it might be a real pain.

Today I was feeling precise (plus I don't like fuzziness and heuristics lol) so I'm giving you an algorithm to compute the best split. It goes through all possible team combinations and for each team calculates the weight (points) differences, returning the teams with the least possible difference.

You can improve this algorithm by stopping if he finds a zero (best possible split) or enumerate only the combinations instead of the permutations, but the asymptotic complexity is the same so I wouldn't bother.

Enjoy

```
class SplitTeams {
  private $_split_weight;
  private $_split_teams;
  private $_players;

  public function __construct($players) {
    $this->_players = array();
    foreach ($players as $p) {
      $this->_players[$p['player_id']] = $p;
    }
  }

  public function getTeams() {
    $this->_list_permutations(array_keys($this->_players), array());

    $half = (int) (count($this->_split_teams) / 2);
    $team_a = array_slice($this->_split_teams, 0, $half);
    $team_b = array_slice($this->_split_teams, $half);
    return array($team_a, $team_b);
  }

  private function _calculate_diff($list) {
    $sum_team_a = 0;
    $sum_team_b = 0;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++) {
      if ($i < (count($list) / 2))
        $sum_team_a += $this->_players[$list[$i]]['Points'];
      else
        $sum_team_b += $this->_players[$list[$i]]['Points'];
    }

    return abs($sum_team_a - $sum_team_b);
  }

  private function _list_permutations($list, $perm) {
    if (count($list) == 0) {
      /* calculate the weight for this split */
      $w = $this->_calculate_diff($perm);
      if (($this->_split_weight === null) ||
          ($this->_split_weight > $w)) {
        /* this is a candidate solution */
        $this->_split_weight = $w;
        $this->_split_teams = $perm;
      }

      print "PERM: " . implode("; ", $perm) . " - weight $w\n";

      return;
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++) {
      // slice array
      $sublist = $list;
      $a = array_splice($sublist, $i, 1);
      $this->_list_permutations($sublist, array_merge($perm, $a));
    }
  }
}

$Data = array(
  array('player_id' => 505, 'Points' => 4),
  array('player_id' => 481, 'Points' => 1),
  array('player_id' => 509, 'Points' => 3),
  array('player_id' => 510, 'Points' => 1),
  array('player_id' => 504, 'Points' => 1),
  array('player_id' => 513, 'Points' => 2));

$s = new SplitTeams($Data);
$teams = $s->getTeams();
print_r($teams);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 505
            [1] => 481
            [2] => 510
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 509
            [1] => 504
            [2] => 513
        )

)
```

**UPDATE** Actually I was joking, this algorithm takes 11 seconds for 8 players, 1 minute for 9 players, and 10 minutes for 10 players :)